# last floated element goes downward in responsive view

Tags: css, responsive-design

Why is that the last element goes downward when the browser is being re-sized?  Here's my markup. It's only the last element that is going down.

```
<div id="bct-items-container">
        <div class="bct-items">
            <img src="assets/images/jobs-icon.png" alt="Jobs"/>
           <h1>2,118</h1>
            <p>Open Jobs</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bct-items">
            <img src="assets/images/careers-head-blue.png" alt="Careers"/>
            <h1>10,300</h1>
            <p>Active Job Seekers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bct-items">
            <img src="assets/images/employer-icon.png" alt="Employers"/>
            <h1>725</h1>
            <p>Prospective Employers</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bct-items">
            <img src="assets/images/handshake2.png" alt="Handshake"/>
            <h1>1,370</h1>
            <p>Positions Placed</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QupAV/41/)

Comment: They all stack vertically if you shrink it down far enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Borders and margins occupy space (in px) and div's widths are in percent and when you resize the window in a small width, the margins and borders (in px) are too big for those percents so the content width will be larger than container width and the last element goes downward and you have a lot of free space so other elements persist on own's places.
You can see what i say when see this JSFiddle:
jsfiddle.net/QupAV/42/

In this sample all of margins and borders are zero and you can resize window to see that all of elements persist on own's places.

If you want to handle this basic problems easily, i highly recommended you to go for something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Comment: Yes i'm aware of bootstrap just want to know the approach for that. Thanks and so i'm accepting this answer.

Comment: The dirty solution (using pure css) is set smaller widths or create nested containers with zero borders and margins and put elements in this containers and the basis solution is using javascript and jquery.